# Dockerfile error no such file or directory"

Tags: docker, deno

I try to use my Dockerfile at [https://labs.play-with-docker.com](https://labs.play-with-docker.com/). Its EOL conversion is LF. My file:

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
RUN curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
WORKDIR /root/.deno/bin
# To print deno version at container start.
CMD ["/root/.deno/bin/deno", "--version"]
```

I start the commands:

```
docker build -t deno .
docker run --rm --name deno deno
```

But I get the error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot create deno docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61793815/cannot-create-deno-docker-image). Alpine is missing `glibc` without which `deno` won't run.

Comment: using ```FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc``` solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

something is wrong with alpine and `deno` installer. it just can execute deno after installation.

Meanwhile this works just fine:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl bash unzip
RUN curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh
CMD ["/root/.deno/bin/deno", "--version"]
```

Comment: Alpine works, it's just missing glibc, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61793815/cannot-create-deno-docker-image

Comment: i meant that deno installer doesn't install properly itself onto apine. no complaints regarding alpine.